# Spekulationen in Antworten

Tags: discussion, answers

Mir fällt auf, dass gerade im Deutschen Teil von Stackexchange dazu geneigt wird, seinen Senf in Form einer Antwort dazuzugeben, auch wenn es nur reine Spekulation ist. Ich finde das senkt deutlich die Qualität diese Seite. Als Beispiel: [Warum nennt man auf Deutsch die Zahlen 0, 2, 4 ... "gerade" Zahlen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/warum-nennt-man-auf-deutsch-die-zahlen-0-2-4-gerade-zahlen)

Sowas wäre mMn besser als Kommentar geeignet und es sollte beim Antwort schreiben angezeigt werden, dass Spekulationen fehl am Platz sind.

Answer (score 10):

> Sowas wäre mMn besser als Kommentar geeignet

Bitte nicht. Kommentare sind absolut nicht für Spekulationen, halbe Antworten u. Ä. gedacht und geeignet. Kommentare können nicht abgewertet werden und es gibt auch keine Möglichkeit, strukturierte Gegenmeinungen zu hinterlassen.

Wenn der Verfasser eine Antwort als zu spekulativ empfindet, soll er sie lieber gar nicht schreiben.

Comment: Grundsätzlich richtig! Aber vor allem, wenn diese Kommentare unter der Frage auftauchen. Wenn sie unter einer Antwort stehen, könnten sie nützlich sein? Zum Beispiel Alternativen vorschlagen?

Comment: @LangLangC: Unter einer Antwort ist eine Vermutung ja noch deplatzierter, es sei denn, es gibt einen direkten Bezug.

Comment: Das natürlich vorausgesetzt, und über die Frage wahrscheinlich auch hergestellt? (Ohne Beispiele halt schwer. Meine natürlich nicht 'irgendwelche'.)

Comment: @LangLangC: Was ich meinte, ist, dass der Zusammenhang zwischen Kommentar und Antwort mehr sein sollte, als dass sie unter derselben Frage stehen. Wenn ja, **kann** der Kommentar eine sinnvolle Ergänzung der Antwort sein.

Comment: Genau. Dein "kann" und mein "wahrscheinlich" haben dasselbe Ziel im Visier. :)

Comment: Es kann nicht downgevotet werden, ja. Aber ein Kommentar wie "Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass das von XY herührt" ist mir lieber als eine Antwort, die im Prinzip das gleiche aussagt, weil es so deutlicher als Spekulation herührt und andere Antworten nicht verdeckt.

Answer (score 6):

Ich sehe es auch so wie du - dass die Qualität der Seite durch Spekulationen häufig abgewertet wird. Deswegen gebe ich in der Regel ein -1 für Spekulationen und begründe das im Kommentar. Mitunter gebe ich dennoch selbst spekulative Antworten. Das erscheint mir gerechtfertigt, wenn davon auszugehen ist, dass wir hier keine bessere Antwort als diese Spekulation erhalten werden. *Ein* Indiz dafür sollte sein, dass einige Tage keine (bessere) Antwort gegeben wurde.

Wenn eine spekulative Antwort als ultima ratio, als besser als gar keine Antwort erscheint, sollte die spekulative Antwort zudem klar ausweisen, dass es sich um Spekulation handelt, und die Spekulation sollte so gut wie möglich begründet werden. Die Antwort sollte unterscheiden zwischen intersubjektiv nachvollziehbaren Gründen und subjektiven Geschmacksfragen, oder "Sprachgefühl" und die jeweiligen Quellen und Indizien für die Spekulation als Begründung angeben. In einem solchen Fall kann auch eine spekulative Antwort einen Mehrwert für die Seite bedeuten. Je detaillierter diese Begründung ist, desto besser kann sich das Publikum eine Meinung über die Wahrscheinlichkeit der Spekulation bilden.

Leider werden manche Fragen regelrecht mit hanebüchenen Spekulationen zugemüllt. Ich bedaure, dass das nicht rigoroser downgevotet wird. In meinen Augen ist das Bewertungssystem von Stack Exchange genau für solche Fälle gemacht. Wenn wir uns aus falscher Rücksicht nicht trauen, schlechte Antworten abzuwerten, dann tun wir der Seite einen Bärendienst. Freundlichkeit im Ton und umsichtiges Vorgehen ist dabei natürlich immer zu wahren.

Comment: Uhl un Nachtigall: diese Antwort wäre deutlich hilfreicher mit Beispielen, die das gemeinte Material verdeutlichen. Es kommen immer Leute, die selbst gut *begründete* and extern *belegte* Argumente als 'spekulant!' ansehen und so kommentieren. Ferner fragen einige explizit nach Dingen, die nur spekulativ beantwortet werden können. – Eine "dies is (nur) spekulativ" Ansage empfinde ich oft als zu flüssig, also überflüssig, wohingegen ich jegliche Begründung einem "ist so" vorziehe. Fehlt die Begründung oder der Beleg, betrachte ich die Antwort sowieso als wenig hilfreich und als Guru-Meditation.

Comment: @LangLangC Es stimmt, eine Definition von "Spekulation" wäre hilfreich. Ich hab ad hoc erstmal keine parat.

Comment: Vielleicht ist das auch doch gar nicht nötig. Vielleicht reicht es einfach, die Kriterien zu überprüfen, die ich im zweiten Absatz vorschlage. Wenn das verletzt ist, dann ist es in jedem Fall eine schlechte Antwort. Ob man es nun "Spekulation" nennt, oder "schlechte Antwort" ist ja eigentlich gleichgültig.

Comment: Ich stimme Dir zu, dass gerade die German community rigoroser mit Downvotes arbeiten sollte.

Answer (score 4):

Auch eine Vermutung kann eine hilfreiche Antwort sein. Denn auch eine Vermutung kann einen Ansatz für eine weitergehende Recherche enthalten, eine neue Idee aufzeigen, neue Lösungsansätze enthalten.

Zwingende Voraussetzung ist aber, dass solch eine Antwort eindeutig gekennzeichnet wird, damit sie unzweifelhaft als Spekulation erkannt werden kann.

Gerade in der genannten Beispielfrage sind viele Antworten als Vermutung erkennbar: "Eine mögliche Erklärung ...", "Meine Vermutung ...", "Ich rate nur ...". Hier wird kein Leser davon ausgehen, dass die Anwort allgemein anerkannt ist. (Im Gegensatz zu vereinzelten Kommentaren, die ohne weiteren Beleg die Vermutung als *falsch* abkanzeln.) Aber man bekommt Ideen, in welche Richtung es gehen könnte. Und noch viel wichtiger: Durch das System der Upvotes und Downvotes zeigt sich auch, welche Vermutungen und Spekulationen von der Community als plausibel eingeschätzt werden und welche nicht.

Meiner Ansicht nach ist es bei solchen Fragen besser, eine Vermutung als (echte) Antwort zu schreiben und nicht als Kommentar. Voraussetzung ist, dass die Vermutung eindeutig als solche gekennzeichnet ist und dass die Vermutung vernünftig erläutert wird.

Answer (score 2):

Ich habe (noch) keine feste Meinung zum Thema.

Einerseits denke ich: je mehr bequellt desto besser gestellt.

Anderseits denke ich: was soll die Fragerin fragen, wenn die Quellen selbst gefunden werden können?

D.h., suche ich lange genug, finde ich alles - und was ich nicht finde, kann ich mir zwar erklären lassen, nur gibt es dafür keine Belege - vulgo Spekulation. Bzw. Meinung. Bzw. Erfahrung.

Spekulation als Kommentar unter der Frage finde ich meist am richtigen Platz, weil ich unterstelle, dass es als Idee / im besten Wissen geschrieben wurde. Und es einen Hinweis geben kann.

Nun antworte ich nur wenn ich glaube es zu wissen (und schreibe dann, dem sei so) - also vermeide ich selbst Antworten, die ich mir aus den Fingern gesaugt habe. Nur kann ich dabei auf die Nase fallen, weil ich lediglich meinen Blickwinkel und Erfahrung einfließen lassen, die objektiv gesehen beide sehr begrenzt sind.

Last but not least: nach [meinem Verständnis](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment) ist es ausreichend, solange in den Kommentaren ein höflicher Umgangston gewahrt und ChitChat in den Chat verlagert wird. Was auch immer in Kommentaren ist, darf als Antwort recycelt werden = für mich: kann ich eine Spekulation belegen, hat der spekulierende Kommentar mir geholfen.

Answer (score 2):

Bin mir bei dem Thema auch etwas unsicher, da ich mich auch frage, ab wann Spekulation beginnt. Rein spekulative Antworten wie die unter der Beispielfrage finde ich auch eher unpassend. Andererseits habe ich auch schon Antworten gegeben, die ich nicht direkt belegen konnte. Oft, weil sich meine Informationen bzw mein Wissen zu der Frage aus dem eigenen Umfeld und Gebrauch zusammensetzt. Manchmal auch nur deshalb, weil ich gerade nicht die nötige Zeit dazu habe, die Quellen zu suchen, jedoch dem Fragenden meine Antwort trotzdem nicht vorenthalten will. *

Gilt das schon als Spekulation oder nur, wenn ich tatsächlich zu einem Thema nur rate? Falls letzteres der Fall ist, stimme ich dem Standpunkt zu.

Zu dem mit den Kommentaren stimme ich eher Wrzlprmft zu. Bis zu einem gewissen Grad können Vermutungen vielleicht weiterhelfen, reine Spekulation finde ich jedoch speziell in Kommentaren unpassend, da man hier z.B. an den Haaren herbeigezogene Behauptungen nicht downvoten kann.

*Interessanterweise sind gerade die Fragen, die ich aus eigener Erfahrung und ohne Quellen beantworte die Bestbewerteten. (Ich persönlich finde andere meiner Antworten weitaus wertvoller)