# Missbrauch der Kommentarfunktion um Antworten zu posten

Tags: discussion

Immer wieder erlebe ich, dass User Fragen in Kommentaren beantworten anstatt richtige Antworten zu schreiben. Beispielsweise hier:

- [Demonstrative pronouns or definitive articles?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/67600/1487)
  Kommentare von [infinitezero](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/30455/infinitezero) und [RDBury](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/43989/rdbury)
- [Different ways to say "why"](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/67583/1487)
  Zweiter Kommentar von [Roland](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/6495/roland)
- ["without offence" in German](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/67588/1487)
  Kommentare von [Roland](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/6495/roland) und [infinitezero](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/30455/infinitezero)
- [Need help to understand sentence structure](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/65938/1487)
  Kommentar von [Roland](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/6495/roland)
- [What does "Was erlauben Sie sich?" mean?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/67564/1487)
  Kommentar von [RDBury](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/43989/rdbury)
- [Brauche Hilfe um einen Satz von einem Roman](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/67572/1487)
  Kommentar von [tofro](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/20363/tofro)
- [Wie verstehe ich "hinaus" von “die Arbeit wird in die Welt hinaus verlagert"](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/67569/1487)
  Kommentar von [Paul Frost](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/34192/paul-frost)

**Was kann man machen, damit weniger Antworten in Kommentare gepackt werden?**

Wenn das ab und zu mal einer macht, ist das ja akzeptabel, aber viele User posten erheblich mehr Antwort-Kommentare auf Fragen als echte Antworten. Ich glaube nicht, dass das der Sinn der Sache ist.

Comment: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment klärt das doch eigentlich. Die Kommentare müssten eben gelöscht werden.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Das passiert aber nicht. Und leider wird das Löschen von Antwort-Kommentaren nicht einfach nur gelegentlich übersehen, sondern sehr konsequent überhaupt nie gemacht.

Comment: Normalerweise müssten answer-in-comment flags reichen?

Answer (score 1):

Ich empfinde das rückstandsfreie Löschen, das in [Please do not answer a question in a comment](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment) angedroht wird, als eine etwas harte Maßnahme. Das Migrieren nützlichen Inhalts in eine eigenständige Antwort (gerne auch als Community wiki) darf jede(r), ist aber nur sehr selten zu beobachten.

Folge-Kommentare, die das Übertragen in eine Antwort vorschlagen, würden helfen, die Verursacher explizit aufmerksam zu machen, während Löschung des Kommentars leicht unbemerkt bleibt.

Das Flag *is no longer needed* ist hier m. E. ohnehin nicht besonders aussagekräftig, ein Flag mit ausführlich ergänztem Text habe ich noch nicht erhalten.

Comment: Folgekommentare führen normalerweise dazu, daß der Nutzer sich verteidigt: Das sei doch nur ein Hinweis und keine Antwort (wie [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/67600/1487) geschehen). Ich empfinde das Löschen in solchen Fällen als völlig angemessen, inbesondere da das in dem fett hervorgehobenen Satz in dem Meta-Post [Please do not answer a question in a comment](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment) auch so angekündigt wird.

Comment: Die meisten Antworten, die als Kommentare gepostet werden, sind zu kurz und unausgegoren um die Umwandlung in eine Antwort zu rechtfertigen. Was Folgekommentare betrifft, stimme ich David zu. Ich setze das Flag *»Something else«* und schreibe als Begründung *»Das ist eine Antwort, die als Kommentar gepostet wurde«.* Es obliegt dann den Moderatoren zu entscheiden, was damit geschehen soll. Möglicherweise fallen den Moderatoren dann auch Wiederholungstäter auf, die sie dann gezielt ansprechen können.