# Löschen von Kommentaren

Tags: discussion

Im Laufe der Zeit sind einige meiner Kommentare verschwunden. Ich gehe davon aus, dass sie gelöscht wurden.

Sicher sind nicht alle Kommentare (auch meine nicht) so gelungen, dass sie erhalten werden müssen.

Meine Fragen: Sollte nicht der Ersteller eines Kommentars über die Löschung und die Gründe dafür informiert werden? Ist das ggf. ein feature request (beim Löschen könnte automatisch eine Nachricht generiert werden)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zur Löschung von Kommentaren gibt es eine ausführliche Diskussion auf [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237978/397134.)

In Anbetracht dessen, dass Kommentare ohnehin eher flüchtiger Natur sind, wird vom System bereits jetzt ein Aufwand betrieben, der mich erstaunt: es gibt extra *Flags*, um darauf hinzuweisen, dass ein Kommentar nicht mehr benötigt wird, damit sich ein Moderator darum kümmert, und bezüglich der Reaktion eine Rückmeldung an den Markierenden geschickt. Selbst in diesem harmlosen Fall (also keine Beleidigungen, etc.) bedeutet das Aufwand für die Moderatoren, zu überprüfen, ob der Kommentar in die Frage/Antwort eingearbeitet wurde oder anderweitig überholt scheint.

Das leidige Verhalten, Antworten in Kommentare zu packen, wurde schon [hier](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/1696) thematisiert und sorgt ebenfalls für eine Grundlast an Kommentarlöschungen.

Ich habe die Erklärung zur Flüchtigkeit ausführlicher in Erinnerung, als auf der von Jonathan verlinkten Seite; ich bin der Auffassung, dass ein Kommentar eine Anzahl von Aufwertungen benötigt, um nicht automatisch gelöscht zu werden - was meines Wissen auch immer noch passieren kann.

Typischerweise benachrichtige ich deswegen **nicht** bei Löschung eines Kommentars, meine Löschschwelle liegt aber vergleichsweise hoch.

---

Bei den "heftigen" Kommentaren würde ich differenzieren:

- Für Kommentare, die versehentlich daneben gegangen sind, oder nur in den falschen Hals geraten *können*, reicht vielleicht eine Entschärfung der Formulierung
- bei den "Gewohnheitstätern" (die kommen sehr selten vor), erscheint mir die Kommentierungssperre als der sinnvollere Ansatz, dann wohl auch mit Nachricht.

Comment: Bemerkenswerter Weise bedeutet "benachrichtigen" in diesem Fall eine persönlich verfasste Nachricht (PM, DM, wie auch immer man das nennen will), die ein Mod erstmal schreiben muss. Das kennen viele User gar nicht, wenn sie noch keine solche Nachricht erhalten haben, denn Direktnachrichten zwischen Nutzern ohne administrativen Bezug gibt es nicht. Da gibt es höchstens den Chat zu öffnen, und die Möglichkeit öffentlich dazu einzuladen, ironischer Weise durch einen Kommentar. Die hiesige Frage begehrt eine bestenfalls automatische Nachricht bei Löschung. Übrigens können Mods das Gelöschte sehen.

Answer (score 3):

Ich lösche tatsächlich Kommentare in der Regel ohne die Betreffenden zu informieren. Es geht dabei nicht um die inhaltliche Qualität des Kommentars, sondern darum, das Rauschen auf der Seite zu verringern, um dem Lesepublikum der Seite einen möglichst unverstellten Zugang auf die relevanten Informationen zu geben.

[Auf Stackexchange sind Kommentare grundsätzlich nicht persistent, sondern flüchtig](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Sie sollen dazu dienen, Nachfragen und Klärungen zu ermöglichen. [Häufig werden Kommentare zweckentfremdet](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment). Ein Feature zur Benachrichtigung halte ich für überflüssig, weil die Kommentare nichts beinhalten sollten, was bewahrenswert ist. In der Regel handelt es sich um einen Missbrauch der Kommentarfunktion, wenn ein Kommentar bewahrenswert erscheint.

Comment: Ein Feature könnte ggf. aus "erzieherischen Gründen" sinnvoll sein.

Comment: Ja, das ist ein Aspekt.

Comment: Die Vorstellung, dass Kommentare den Zugang zu relevanten Informationen verstellen können, finde ich belustigend. Könntest Du einen Beispielthread zeigen, in dem ein Kommentar das tut?

Comment: @userunknown Wenn unter einer Antwort viele Kommentare stehen, muss man die als Leser lesen, weil man vermutet, dass sie relevant seien. Wenn sie das nicht sind, verschlechtern sie das Signal-Rausch-Verhältnis: Man braucht mehr Zeit und muss mehr Aufwand betreiben, um die relevante Information zu bekommen.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Das stimmt nicht, man muss nicht die Kommentare lesen. Im Gegenteil haben wir die Richtlinie, das Korrekturen und Wichtiges ins Posting übernommen werden sollen. Auch wenn Kommentare unwichtiges enthalten verstellen sie nicht den Zugang zur Information - das hieße, dass man an die Information nicht rankommt und ist was anderes, als das Signal-Rausch-Verhältnis. Zumal man ja mit dem eigentlichen Text beginnt und nicht mit den Kommentaren ist das Bild des verstellten Zugangs abwegig.

Comment: @userunknown Wir sollten nicht davon ausgehen, dass unsere Leser:innen unsere Richtlinien kennen. Ob "verstellen" das richtige Wort ist, darüber brauchen wir nicht zu streiten. Entscheidend ist, dass das Signal-Rausch-Verhältnis verschlechtert wird - und dass das schlecht für die Leser:innen ist.

Comment: Die meisten Leute brauchen keine Richtlinie, um einen Artikel vor den Kommentaren zu lesen. Und RL braucht man nicht, wenn sich niemand danach richten soll. Wofür soll es entscheidend sein, wie das Signal/Rauschen-Verhältnis ist? Ob das so schlecht für sie ist, können die Leser ja selbst entscheiden. Beispielsweise könnte jmd. meinen Kommentar weglöschen. Dann kommt aber vielleicht ein neuer Leser, stolpert auch über das "Verstellen" und verfasst einen neuen. Oder ich selbst stolper in 3 Jahren drüber, wenn der Beitrag noch mal aufpoppt, und hole den vermeintlich versäumten Kommentar nach.

Comment: @userunknown Die Leserin muss zusätzlichen Aufwand betreiben, um zu erfahren oder sicherzustellen, dass in den Kommentaren nichts Relevantes steht.

Comment: "*In der Regel handelt es sich um einen Missbrauch ..*." Was ist "Es"? Da liegt ein Zirkelschluss vor: Im Sinne der Regel sind die Kommentare, die gelöscht werden sollen, missbräuchlich, also sind gelöschte Kommentare, bzw. der Modus Operandi dahinter ("es"), wohl missbräuchlich gewesen! Allerdings stehen die Regeln, die den Nießbrauch beschreiben, auf einem anderen Blatt. Dort steht nichts davon, "das Rauschen auf der Seite zu verringern". Richtig ist es zwar trotzdem, geriert sich aber zu oft derart, dass Kritik an vereinfachten Antworten ausgeblendet wird, damit es(!) irgendwie gut aussieht

Comment: *"... weil die Kommentare nichts beinhalten sollten, was bewahrenswert ist."* Sorry, aber ehrlich mal. Es ist sehr häufig einfacher, es bei einem Kommentar zu belassen, als dass irgendwer den Inhalt, der dem Sinn durchaus zuträglich sein sollte, in eine entsprechende Antwort einarbeitet. Das ist Usus, und die Grundsatzregelung nur ein Lippenbekenntnis. *Flüchtigkeit* ist daher zu höchst relativ. Ebenso ist relativ, wie sinnvoll man die "Kritik" im einzelfall einstuft, von wegen "Es geht dabei nicht um die inhaltliche Qualität, ...". Was ist *Rauschen* denn sonst, wenn nicht belangloser Inhalt?

Comment: Heute sind zwei meiner (auch wenn ich das selber sage:) hilfreichen Kommentare verschwunden. Kommentarlos, wie es hier üblich zu sein scheint. Jetzt stehe ich vor der Wahl, in Zukunft öfters Antworten zu schreiben (selbst wenn es mE ein Kommentar täte), oder mich in diesem SX einfach wieder weniger einzubringen. Scheint jedenfalls eine deutsche Unart, pardon: Eigenschaft zu sein, die ich aus anderen SXen nicht kenne. Und, ganz ehrlich, auch nicht schätze. Moderation ist schön und gut, darf aber gerne ein bisschen weniger *heavy-handed* sein.

Comment: @Ingmar Ja, ich habe deine Kommentare gelöscht. Ziel ist es dabei natürlich, dich zu Option 1 deiner Wahl zu bewegen. :) Schreib doch eine Antwort - das ist der geradlinigere Weg in die Gehirne des zukünftigen Lesepublikums der Frage.

Answer (score 3):

Alleine die Diskussion, die in den Kommentaren von @jonathan.scholbach zwische ihm und @user unknown abgeführt wird, zeigt, daß das Löschen von Kommentaren vielleicht doch keine so gute Idee ist, wie das ihm dargestellt wird.

Sollte diese Diskussion nämlich substantiell sein - und ich denke, wir stimmen darin überein, daß sie das ist - dann ist sie durchaus erhaltenswert. @jonathan.scholbach wird nun sicher einwenden, bzw. hat bereits eingewandt:

> In der Regel handelt es sich um einen Missbrauch der Kommentarfunktion, wenn ein Kommentar bewahrenswert erscheint.

Dann stellt sich doch die Frage, wo genau eben jener Austausch hätte stattfinden sollen, wenn nicht in den Kommentaren? Dieser Thread hier ist doch das beste Beispiel dafür, weshalb Kommentare Bewahrenswertes enthalten können und of sogar müssen: wenn nämlich zu einer bestimmten Frage divergierende Antworten möglich sind und dieser Umstand einer Diskussion unter den Antwortenden zugeführt wird, dann hat diese Diskussion:

1. Für den Fragesteller bzw. Antwortsuchenden durchaus Informationsgehalt und ist deshalb bewahrenswert.
2. Aufgrund der Form und Struktur des Forums keinen anderen Platz als die Kommentarfunktion

Davon abgesehen: wenn Du das Signal-/Rauschverhältnis verbessern willst, dann müßtest Du *inhaltlich* bewerten, was bewahrenswert ist und was nicht, anstatt es nur einfach an der Lokation - Kommentar oder Artikel - festzumachen. Nur deshalb, weils in einem Artikel steht, ist das Geschriebene ja nicht notwendigerweise von höherem Signalwert als der darunterstehende Kommentar.

Dann stellt sich aber die Frage, warum nicht Artikel ebenfalls gelöscht werden? Wenn denn zu viele Antworten unter einer Frage stehen, dann "verstellen" diese den Zugang zur (vermeintlich vollständigen) Information ja genauso durch ihre Anwesenheit wie die Kommentare, oder?

---

PS: solltest Du Dich fragen, warum ich das nicht als Kommentar unter Deine Antwort geschrieben habe: wenn ich meinen Beitrag zu dieser Diskussion sowieso für entbehrlich hielte, dann hätte ich gar nicht erst zu antworten brauchen, weder als Kommentar noch als Antwort.

Comment: *"Dann stellt sich aber die Frage, warum nicht Artikel ebenfalls gelöscht werden?"* Das passiert durchaus, außer in Ausnahmenfällen durch die Bewertung der Nutzer, oft im Verhältnis zu anderen Antworten. Da Kommentare ebenso bewertet werden können, und gewisser Maßen auch sortiert sind, ist der Unterschied relativ gering. Die Frage stellt sich jedenfalls nicht hier, weil bei Löschung von Antworten durchaus eine automatische Antwort generiert wird.

Comment: *"Dann stellt sich doch die Frage, wo genau eben jener Austausch hätte stattfinden sollen, wenn nicht in den Kommentaren?"* Gegebenfalls in den Antworten, wobei der Austausch dann nur noch durch Editieren eigener Antworten, bzw. über Synthese gegebener Antworten in einer dritten statthaft ist. Das ist offensichlich unpraktikabel. Dafür wurde der Chat eingerichtet, der aber kaum angenommen wird, und hauptsächlich von Mods und deren Anhängern für Smalltalk verwendet wird. Denn idealer Weise wären sich die *Experten* ohnehin über alles Relevante des Themengebiets einig. Diese "Experten", bwahaha.

Comment: Ferner schlägt der Vergleich von meta und der hauptseite hinsichtlich der Diskussion in Kommentaren leider fehl. Hier sind auch die Antworten häufiger wie Diskussionen, Meinungsbilder oder ähnliches strukturiert.

Comment: Nur ein Gedanke zu: "Nur deshalb, weils in einem Artikel steht, ist das Geschriebene ja nicht notwendigerweise von höherem Signalwert als der darunterstehende Kommentar." Es liegt in der Natur des Bewertungssystems, dass die Community das Signal-Rausch-Verhältnis bei Antworten verbessert. Bessere Antworten kommen nach vorn, schlechtere nach hinten. Das ist gerade bei Kommentaren nicht der Fall.

Comment: Zu "Dann stellt sich doch die Frage, wo genau eben jener Austausch hätte stattfinden sollen, wenn nicht in den Kommentaren?" - dafür ist der Chat da.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: Der Chat wird aber - da gebe ich vectory ausnahmsweise recht - eben nicht angenommen. Das ist ein Fakt und möglicherweise bedauerlich, aber eben Fakt. Zum Signalwert: mag sein, daß das Signal-Rausch-Verhältnis durch das Bewertungssystem tendenziell verbessert wird, aber das ändert nichts daran, daß Antworten prinzipiell entbehrlich sein *können* und Kommentare prinzipiell wertvolle Information enthalten *können*. Um das mit einem Vergleich aus der Mathematik zu illustrieren: X<10 und Y<5 heißt nicht, daß Y kleiner sein muß als X.