# Löschen von Kommentaren bei Verstoß gegen den Code of Conduct

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Dies ist eine Ergänzungsfrage zu [Löschen von Kommentaren](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1664/34192).

Ich akzeptiere, dass die Moderatoren die Entscheidungshoheit über das Löschen von Kommentaren haben und dass Kommentare ohne Benachrichtigung gelöscht werden können.

Wird das auch so praktiziert, wenn ein Kommentar gegen den Code of Conduct verstößt und ggf. ein Flag der Typen

- It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse.
  This comment attacks a person or group.
- It's unfriendly or unkind.
  This comment is rude or condescending.

erhalten hat? Eine kommenarlose Löschung sollte hier m.E. nicht erfolgen. Der Kommentator sollte explizit auf sein Verhalten aufmerksam gemacht werden.

Answer (score 3):

Die Frage muss im Kontext des gesamten Sanktionsregimes gesehen werden: Wenn jemand öfter gegen den Code of Conduct verstößt, gibt es Eskalationsszenarien (die wir auch tatsächlich schon beschritten haben). Ein nächster Schritt ist, dass wir die Betreffenden anschreiben. Die nächste Eskalationsstufe ist eine temporäre Sperrung.

Wenn ich mich recht erinnere, habe ich die Flag bisher nur *It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse. This comment attacks a person or group.* nur in eindeutigen oder sogar krassen Fällen gesehen. In der Regel kommt der betreffende Post von Leuten, die hier neu sind - ein gutes Zeichen dafür, dass das Sanktionsregime funktioniert. In solch einem Fall habe ich den Beitrag gelöscht und einen Kommentar hinterlassen, um die Grenzen des Code of Conduct deutlich zu machen.

Öfter schonmal allerdings habe ich *It's unfriendly or unkind. This comment is rude or condescending.* gesehen. In dem Fall lasse ich mitunter einen Kommentar da, mitunter nicht. Wenn die Flag von der betroffenen Person kam - das waren in der Regel Neulinge (und das ist ein schlechtes Zeichen, denn es bedeutet, dass die Leute, die schon länger dabei sind, ein anderes Level von Freundlichkeit für normal halten, als Leute aus dem Rest der Welt) - dann hinterlasse ich immer einen Kommentar.

Ich finde einen Großteil der Kommentare auf german.SE zumindest "unkind" (was ich mit "nicht nett" übersetze), gerade was den Umgang mit Neulingen angeht. Ich kann aber nicht jedesmal einen Kommentar hinterlassen, weil die Einschätzungen hier deutlich auseinandergehen. Ich habe schon Rückmeldungen erhalten, in denen Dritte verteidigt haben, dass eine Reaktion durchaus nicht als "unkind" einzustufen wäre. Diese Bewertung ist in meinen Augen eine Frage der gesamten Kultur. Kommentare einzelner Mods können zu dieser Kultur nur einen (geringen) Teil beitragen. Die Kultur wird maßgeblich von den Leuten geprägt, die viele (inhaltlich gute) Antworten und Kommentare hinterlassen. Am Ende ist die Vorstellung dieser Leute -- die ja auch die Seite inhaltlich am Leben halten -- maßgeblich für das Freundlichkeitslevel der Seite.