# Meine Kommentare verschwinden …

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

Heute ist zweimal von mir ein Kommentar unter einem Posting sang- und klanglos verschwunden. Anstößig oder auch nur inhaltlich unpassend waren beide nicht. Ist das hier so üblich? Wenn es eine Moderationsentscheidung war: derartige Eingriffe bin ich aus anderen SXen nicht gewohnt.

Comment: Das ist leider eine viel zu häufig zu beobachtende Unart unserer Moderatoren. Auch ich beobachte das immer wieder und ich ärgere mich sehr darüber. Allerdings gibt es Kommentare, die hier tatsächlich nichts zu suchen haben: Kommentare, in denen versucht wird, eine gestellte Frage zu beantworten. Denn genau dafür gibt es die Möglichkeit, Antworten zu posten. Da ich deine Kommentare nicht kenne, kann ich nicht sagen, ob das vielleicht der Grund war. Siehe: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment

Comment: Danke, Hubert. Es waren Kommentare aus denen man, mit ein bisschen gutem Willen und Mehraufwand auch eine Antwort machen hätte können, aber im Prinzip ursprüngliches, erstes Feedback, ein bisschen Nachfragen, etc. Sollte das die Frage beantwortet haben, kenne ich aus anderen SXen eher die Aufforderung, daraus eine "echte" Antwort zu machen, als die kommentarlose Löschung. Meiner intrinsischen Motivation ist es insgesamt jedenfalls eher abträglich.

Comment: Ich flagge selbst relativ häufig Antwort-Kommentare, damit die Moderatoren darauf aufmerksam werden und sie dann löschen. Ich finde es aber sehr schade, dass es in Stackexchange keinen Mechanismus gibt, der den Autor des Kommentars über die Löschung informiert. Immerhin hat sich der Autor des Kommentars ja mit guten Absichten die Mühe gemacht, den Lesern sein Wissen bereitzustellen, und da gehört es sich - wie ich finde - schon, den Autor wenigstens zu informieren. Aber offenbar besteht die einzige Möglichkeit einer solchen Information darin, selbst wieder einen Kommentar zu ...

Comment: ... hinterlassen, was dann manchmal eine Lawine von Folgekommentaren nach sich zieht, die sich dann nur um den Löschvorgang als solchen drehen, also off-topic sind, und daher auch gelöscht werden sollten. Daher wählen die Moderatoren offenbar den Weg, solche Kommentare einfach kommentarlos zu löschen. (Das ist eine Vermutung, ich bin selbst ja kein Moderator.)

Comment: Dafür werden Antworten, die völlig fehl am Platze sind, in Kommentare umgewandelt, um nicht unfreundlich gegenüber Erstschreibern zu erscheinen ;)